# LiveWire run function on field update in Dynamic rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using LiveWire for the rows in a order.
Every row has a package and the ordered amount of the package.

I need to check if a package is available on the given delivery date.

This is my mount method in the LiveWire controller:

```
public function mount()
    {
        $rows = [];
        $orderLines = OrderLine::with('package')->where('order_id', $this->order->id)->get();
        foreach($orderLines as $orderLine) {
            if(is_null($orderLine->title)){
                $rows[] = [
                    'package_id' => $orderLine->package_id,
                    'amount' => $orderLine->amount,
                    'checking' => 0,
                    'db_id' => $orderLine->id
                ];
            }
        }
        $this->fill([
            'orderLines' => collect($rows),
        ]);
    }
```

This is my updated fields function:

```
public function updatedorderLines(){
        $orderTotal = 0;
        foreach($this->orderLines as &$orderLineRow){
            $orderLine = OrderLine::find($orderLineRow['db_id']);
            $orderLine->package_id = $orderLineRow['package_id'];
            $orderLine->amount = $orderLineRow['amount'];
            $totals = PackagesController::packageCalculateTotals($orderLine->package_id);
            $orderLine->cost_ex_vat = $totals['customTotals']['price_ex_vat'] ;
            $orderTotal += ($orderLine->cost_ex_vat * $orderLine->amount);
            $orderLine->cost_inc_vat = $totals['customTotals']['price_inc_vat'];
            $orderLine->vat_9 = $totals['customTotals']['vat_9'];
            $orderLine->vat_21 = $totals['customTotals']['vat_21'];
            $orderLine->save();
        }
    }
```

What I need is to update the checking to 1 or 2 depending on the availability. (1 is available, 2 is sold out.)

At some point I need to call the `getStockOnDate($packageId, $date)` function, this returns the amount of packages available on the given date. In the `updatedorderLines()` I need to run this function and update the `checking` of the orderline.

On the frontend blade file I have this:

```
 @foreach($orderLines as $key => $orderLine)
        <div class="disFlex fdCol row">
            <div class="section__grid disGrid row disGrid--twoColumns--small pb10 mb5 bBottom--dashed">
                <div class="section__row__col disFlex fdCol">
                    <label class="bold cBlack">Pakket:
                        @if($orderLine['checking'] == 0)
                            <div title="Voorraad aan het controleren..." style="height: 10px; width: 10px; " class="spinner"></div>
                        @endif
                        @if($orderLine['checking'] == 1)
                            <i title="Pakket is op voorraad op de geselecteerde leverdatum" class="fal fa-check-circle cGreen"></i>
                        @endif
                        @if($orderLine['checking'] == 2)
                            <i title="Pakket is niet op voorraad op de geselecteerde leverdatum" class="far fa-times-circle cRed"></i>
                        @endif
                    </label>
                    <div class="selectWrapper row">
                        <select @if($order->is_exported) disabled @endif name="status" wire:model.lazy="orderLines.{{$key}}.package_id">
                            @foreach($packages as $package)
                                <option value="{{$package->id}}">{{$package->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section__row__col disFlex">
                    <div class="section__row__col disFlex fdCol row">
                        <label class="bold cBlack">Aantal:</label>
                        <div class="row disFlex jcSB nw">
                            <input @if($order->is_exported) readonly @endif wire:model.lazy="orderLines.{{$key}}.amount" type="number" class="row">
                            @if(!$order->is_exported)
                                <span wire:click="removeItem({{$key}})" data-pakket="true" class="btn red ml10"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

The problem I have is, if I add the `getStockOnDate($packageId, $date)` in the updated function and change the `checking` field of the orderLine, nothing happens. How do I check the stock when a field changes and update the checking variable so that the frontend changes to a check or a cross?

Answer (score 0):

The `mount` method only runs once (when building the component). So if you're updating the `$orderLine` model, it will update your database but not your Livewire state, since you're not explicitly updating your `$orderLines` variable.

Best practice would be to update the specific index. While it might seem simple to change `mount` to `render` (`render` triggers every render cycle), this will make lots more requests since you're refetching the orderlines every render cycle, and make the page a lot slower.

Exampe snippet (for the idea):

```php
foreach($this->orderLines as $index => $orderLineRow) {
    $orderLine = OrderLine::find($orderLineRow['db_id']);
    $orderLine->package_id = $orderLineRow['package_id'];
    //
    //
    $date = now();
    $checking = getStockOnDate($getStockOnDate($packageId, $date), $date);
    $this->orderLines[$index]['checking'] = $checking;
    $orderLine->checking = $checking;
    $orderLine->save();
}
```

P.S. If possible I would suggest not using arbitrary numbers for a status. I would use `const` strings. If not possible, I'd at least documentate it somewhere. If you come back to this project later, or if another developer works on it, 0, 1 and 2 might not be very straight forward in their meaning.

P.P.S. I would also suggest [`wire:key`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-cures) on your rows:

```
<div class="disFlex fdCol row" wire:key="{{ $orderLine['db_id'] }}">
```

This will allow Livewire to keep better track of your rows.